# Inserting values from a list into excel(The code only append one value) Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, list, openpyxl

I am trying to insert values from a list into excel, I know that I can use a dictionary and will do the same, but I would like to do it this way from a list. The code appends the value but appends only one value.  For instance, in the column appears the value of Salsa. Thank you in advance!

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Python_Example.xlsx")
list_of_music=list(sheet.columns)[4] #With this I can loop over the column number 4 cells 
favorite_music= ['Rock','Bachata','Salsa']
for cellObj in list_of_music: 
   for item in favorite_music: 
       cellObj.value = str(item)  

wb.save("Python_Example.xlsx")
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and see [ask] for more tips on asking good questions. You should also tell us what your current output is an include or include error messages if there is no output

Comment: Thank you!! I formatted the code, I would like to know why the only value that appear in the column 4 is Salsa. The enumarate works perfectly but I would like to know why my nested for loop is doesn't working.

Comment: That is because for each cell in the column, you change it's value 3 times (each value in `favourite_music`). As `"Salsa"` is the last item in the list, that's what is left in your file when you open it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) docs; they include some good basic tutorials that will help you, especially for iterating over ranges of cells. `iter_rows` and `iter_cols` are also very useful tools that may help you here. A simple solution would consist of:

```
import openpyxl as op

# Create example workbook
wb = op.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
favourite_music = ['Rock','Bachata','Salsa']

for i, music in enumerate(favourite_music):
    ws.cell(row=i+1, column=4).value = music

wb.save('Example.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! enumerate function works great! I don't know why my code appears in a different way. Indeed my code has no error the only thing is  that only paste one value the value is Salsa. I already have the excel sheet created, that's why I used load_workbook.